# SSMS Intellisense is not consistent

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

I have a problem with my SSMS. For every 5 minutes of interval Intellisense
is not working. Is there something wrong with my SSMS software or something wrong with the local server.

I won't say it is not working but it is not consistent. Can anyone give me a insight of whats the problem.

I tired Refreshing Local cache(`Ctrl+shift+R`) with no luck. For next 5 minutes it will work then it wont work.

Comment: you have 21.7K on Stack Overflow... you should know by now that you need to give us more information in order for us to help you with this issue.

Comment: @TarynEast - Nothing more to explain. If you have SSMS knowledge you can easily understand problem

Comment: Are there any corresponding log entries?

Comment: Please expand upon "will not work" - what do you observe happening? What did you expect to happen instead? Under what circumstances? What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: @TarynEast - Do you know the functionality of Intellisense. After some research i found that (Ctrl+shift+R) will help to resolve the problem but no lock.

Comment: @suslov -Sorry to ask what do you mean by "log entries". I dont have DBA knowledge. Can you explain

Comment: You added more info after I wrote my original statement. No - I do not know much about intellisense... don't forget that people that don't know your software will probably look at your question (because you're tagged SQL and sql-server... and people interested in those tags will also look). Making your question intelligible to these people is not a difficult thing - and helps us to figure out whether or not we can be of help... or whether we should move on to help somebody else. If your question was clearer, that would have helped me to decide whether or not to help you...

Comment: But still... as a 21.7K user, I'd hope you were a good example to others on how to ask questions... and in other questions, people are expected not to use the phrase "it's not working" but explain what they actually see... I'm sure you've had your share of "it's broken, what's wrong with it" questions here ;)

Comment: I've found SSMS intellisense to be .... sporadic at best. Use a different components one instead.

Comment: By not working do you mean nothing pops up, or an out of date list pops up, or it pops up when you don't want it to, or it blows up your monitor? Just some suggestions to try and get you to expand your explanation... third time lucky

Comment: Are you changing underlying schema in between when you refresh the cache and when it stops working? If so, understand that SSMS doesn't poll the database unless you tell it to. That is, it's good for schema that's not in flux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install `sqlcompletefree.exe` for the Intellisense. It's free version of Sql Server intellisense.

You will get it from the below link

[dbForge SQL Complete Express](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1e8064cb-58d8-4eb3-a88c-d8f9a167ccca)

Answer (score 0):

If SQL server you are connected to is very busy with CPU or IO intensive load, intellisense may be lagging as well. As it is async, you may be happily typing away, but not getting any code completion. I found that due to an extreme case where the host was pinning CPU and SQL server was slow, but ran queries fine, while intellisense did not work at all. As soon as I got the admin to kill the runaway service, intellisense immediately started working again, while "small" query performance hardly changed.